# how to make string default value null in hyperledger composer model file

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I want to make default value of a string parameter in a asset as null

for example

```
o String param
```

i should give default value of param as null.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't set a default value of `null` in the model file, and if you try and set it to `null` in a Transaction Function it will not be set and will be undefined.

If you create it as an Optional field and do not set a value it will still be undefined.

You can set a default of `""` - an empty string. Which will return a `typeof` String rather than undefined.

You don't specify why you want null, but with both the empty string or the undefined value they should both return false to the test `!(param)`

Answer (score 0):

Put default value like this

```
o String param default=""
```